# adding vlv(virtual list view) extension to openLDAP (LDAP) Server

Tags: ldap, openldap, laravel, ldapmodule

Im currently working with LDAPRecord library in a Laravel project. I want to use a pagination function but it's required having virtual list view (vlv) extension to my ldap server

, I dont quite know the steps to add it but from what i found , I created a ldif file in \etc\ldap\slapd.d\cn=config\cn=module{1}.ldif [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcnv9.jpg) then I use the ldapmodify command[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhoM4.png) but as you can see it shows an error message , can you help ??